# Can not activate discussions on Plone Dexterity types (folderish)

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have been working on a dexterity based plone application.
I have created a couple of new types. This is what I did to activate comments on a specific dexterity content type named "activity_report":

**In Plone Control Panel**

In the *Discussion* section I enabled the following:

- globally enable comments
- enable anonymous comments

In the *Types* Section 
I chose the "Activity Report" type from the drop down and enabled the "Allow comments" option.

**On the file system**

In the FTI file activityreport.xml:

```
<property name="allow_discussion">True</property>
```

I have restarted the instance and even reinstalled the product, but I can not activate the comments section in the dexterity type.

It is worth mentioning that a standard type (ex. Page) can have the discussion module activated.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think my problem is also related to the fact that my content type is folderish. How do I allow discussion on a folderish type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plone.app.discussion currently disables commenting for all containers (see https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11245 for discussion).

I used a monkey patch like the following in one project to short-circuit the normal check and make sure that commenting was enabled for my folderish content type:

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner
from Products.highcountrynews.content.interfaces import IHCNNewsArticle
from plone.app.discussion.conversation import Conversation
old_enabled = Conversation.enabled
def enabled(self):
    parent = aq_inner(self.__parent__)
    if parent.portal_type == 'my_portal_type':
        return True
    return old_enabled(self)
Conversation.enabled = enabled
```

where 'my_portal_type' is, of course, the portal_type you want commenting enabled for.

Comment: Thanks David! This looks like the solution I will adopt. I am also considering turning the types into simple documents. In my case, the only advantage using folderish types would have been to keep related documents together in the container.

Answer (score 2):

The David response is not accurate. The class to be monkeypatched is *plone.app.discussion.browser.conversation.ConversationView* :

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner
from plone.app.discussion.browser.conversation import ConversationView
old_enabled = ConversationView.enabled

def enabled(self):
    parent = aq_inner(self.__parent__)
    if parent.portal_type == 'My_type':
        return True
    return old_enabled(self)
```

It works for Plone 4.2 at least. However, thanks David for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

As David and Victor already pointed out, you can just override the enable method of the conversation class. I would recommend using the following approach which is a bit cleaner than monkey patching the conversation class:

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.discussion/blob/master/docs/source/howtos/howto_override_enable_conversation.txt

I also added support for dexterity types to plone.app.discussion recently, so as soon as there is a new release you won't need to customize the conversation class any longer:

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.discussion/commit/0e587a7d8536125acdd3bd385e880b60d6aec28e

Note that this method supports commenting ON folderish objects. There is no support to enable/disable commenting for objects INSIDE a folderish object yet.

In case you want to be able to switch on/off commenting with a behavior field/widget:

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.dexterity/commit/0573df4f265a39da9efae44e605e3815729457d7

This will hopefully make it into the next plone.app.dexterity release as well.

Comment: Nice solution as all the changes are outside any plone package eggs.  The "howto_override_enable_conversation.txt" mostly worked for me.  Before "if context.allow_discussion is not None" I had to check if the attribute exists in context (or added a try, catch block).

Comment: @RyanAnderson would you mind changing the howto and doing a pull request so I can update the docs?

Answer (score 1):

I solved in configure.zcml:

```
<interface interface="Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.INonStructuralFolder" />

<class class="Products.PloneHelpCenter.types.Definition.HelpCenterDefinition">
  <implements interface="Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.INonStructuralFolder" />
</class>
```

UPDATE: this is not a good idea. I had problems with missing Add menu for each content type having this fix.