# How to add the is_folderish attribute to Dexterity objects?

Tags: plone, dexterity

The `.is_folderish` attribute is used in many places. For example when [setting an object as the default view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176176/how-can-i-add-a-dexterity-content-type-as-the-default-view) or when [activating discussions on an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402918/can-not-activate-discussions-on-plone-dexterity-types-folderish).

My first question is how to check is an object has that attribute set. I tried using the `bin/instance debug` with something like this:

```python
>>> app.site.news.is_folderish
...
AttributeError: is_folderish
```

I imagine that I can't reach attributes on that way because `app.site.news` is a wrapper to the object that has that attribute.

My second question is how to add that attribute to a new Dexterity object. I suppose I can do it using the code below (but I can't test it before the my first question is resolved).

```python
from zope import schema
from plone.dexterity.content import Item

class IHorse(form.Schema):
    ...

class Horse(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Horse, self).__init__(id)
        is_folderish = False
```

But I'm not sure about how both classes could be linked.

Comment: I amended my previous comment; `is_folderish` is the index, `isPrincipiaFolderish` the object attribute. This is set on Dexterity objects, see [the source](https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/master/plone/dexterity/content.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `is_folderish` to your types; it is an index in the catalog, and Dexterity types already have the proper attribute for that index, `isPrincipiaFolderish`.

If you *do* need to add attributes to content types, you can either use an event subscriber or create a custom subclass of `plone.dexterity.content.Item`:

- [subscribers](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/five.grok/core-components/events) can listen for the `IObjectCreatedEvent` event:

  ```python
  from zope.app.container.interfaces import IObjectAddedEvent

  @grok.subscribe(IYourDexterityType, IObjectCreatedEvent)
  def add_foo_attribute(obj, event):            
      obj.foo = 'baz'
  ```
- [custom content classes](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/classes) need to be registered in your type XML:

  ```python
  from plone.dexterity.content import Item

  class MyItem(Item):
      """A custom content class"""
      ...
  ```

  then in your Dexterity FTI XML file, add a `klass` property:

  ```xml
  <property name="klass">my.package.myitem.MyItem</property>
  ```